# Display Post Card Based On User Screen

Tags: wordpress, resolution, responsive

I developed a website in wordpress, In which in each row I have 3 cards and in total 9.

Website is responsive, when I shrink the size, the number of post (cards) become 2 in each row. The issue is, I want even number of cards in each row I reduce the browser size. Is this possible to hide the last post when I reduce the website so instead of displaying 8 post (cards) 2 in each row? instead of 9 post?

Please give me some suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question should include a a summary of what you have already tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Update your answer with these so we have enough information to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media css.
First give a custom class to you last card.
Write below code in your custom css.

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
.classname {
    display:none;
}
}
```

write class name of you last card on the place of classname and give size of the screen below which you want to hide the card.